How do I access dynamically created objects and their properties in JavaScript?
If I write a function that creates a new person and attach it to an onClick event on a button, how can I access the data that was entered without a variable name?
When a user presses the button, the user can enter values when prompts come up, but nothing prints to the console upon completion?
I tried the followng code:
     <button type="submit" onClick="addNewPerson()">Add New Person</button>

     class Person {
       constructor(fname, lname, birthDate) {
         this.firstName = fname;
         this.lastName = lname;
         this.dov = birthDate;
       }
     }

     let person1 = new Person("Mark", "Johnson", "12-07-1972");
     let person2 = new Person("John", "Miller", "08-017-1923");

     function addNewPerson() {
       let ffname = prompt("enter your firstname", "Roger");
       let llname = prompt("enter your lastname", "Doger");
       let ddov = prompt("enter your date of birth", "July 6 2024");

       return new Person(ffname, llname, ddov);
     }

      console.log(addNewPerson())
      console.log(person1); 
      console.log(person2); 
      console.log(new Person(this.fname, this.lname, this.birthDate));

What I was expecting - When the button is clicked, the values entered into the prompts would be displayed in the console. It does not. This code only prints the following to the console:
    Object { firstName: "Roger", lastName: "Doger", dov: "July 6 2024" }
    Object { firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Johnson", dov: "12-07-1972" }
    Object { firstName: "John", lastName: "Miller", dov: "08-017-1923" }
    Object { firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined, dov: undefined }


The return value of an onclick function isn't saved anywhere. addNewPerson() can update the DOM, update a global variable, etc.

If you want the button click to display something in the console, put console.log() inside the function.

It's not clear why you would expect subsequent button clicks to print anything to the console. You have console logging statements after the function declarations, but those have nothing to do with the button clicks.

The dynamically created person objects are not being stored or referenced properly outside the"addNewPerson" function
A different approach is to store dynamically created persons in an array
class Person {
      constructor(fname, lname, birthDate) {
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.dov = birthDate;
      }
    }

    let persons = [];

    let person1 = new Person("Mark", "Johnson", "12-07-1972");
    let person2 = new Person("John", "Miller", "08-17-1923");

    persons.push(person1);
    persons.push(person2);

    function addNewPerson() {
      let ffname = prompt("Enter your firstname", "Roger");
      let llname = prompt("Enter your lastname", "Doger");
      let ddov = prompt("Enter your date of birth", "July 6 2024");

      let newPerson = new Person(ffname, llname, ddov);
      persons.push(newPerson);

      console.log(newPerson); 
    }
console.log(persons); 
console.log(person1); 
console.log(person2);


Sure - you are welcome

That solution works!

Sure you are welcome
